# How to search for word patterns with lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am indexing dictionary words using lucene's MemoryIndex in-memory search index.

I am not indexing sentences, but just single words or compound-words.

How can I search for patterns in a word like:

1. begins with
2. ends with
3. contains

So example words I would be indexing are:

```
car
boat
singlehome
apartment
programmer
hello
and
last
first
```

So based on the example linked in the comments I do this:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer(version);
 MemoryIndex index = new MemoryIndex();

 index.addField("word", "car", analyzer);
 index.addField("word", "boat", analyzer);
 index.addField("word", "singlehome", analyzer);
 index.addField("word", "apartment", analyzer);

 QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(version, "content", analyzer);
```

**Update**
Is the above code correct?

Is there a way that I could somehow categorize the words, so I could only search for words in a given category?

Comment: Does this answer your question?   http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/memory/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/MemoryIndex.html.   Read the examples at the start.

Comment: @StephenC I updated my Q, is that the right idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WildcardQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/WildcardQuery.html). Allowed wildcards are [*,?,].

Use it like:

```
Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("contents", "prog*"));
Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("contents", "*er"));
```

Please note that queries starting with * in start may be slow in runtime. A working [wildcard query example](http://howtodoinjava.com/lucene/lucene-wildcardquery-search-example/).